# Shell Script to display menu

Tags: bash, shell, menu

I have some problem in my Shell script,
I have written one very short example but i am not getting the expected output,
I have used `if` condition inside the `case` Statement, but have some failure..
Well, my question is:
when I press `2`, then user should give the path first to search for file and if no path is given then I will look in Default path as I have mentioned,
but I can not get this function here, can anyone help me on this regards? please
I would be thankful for your help :)

my code is:

```
#!/bin/bash
trap '' 2
while true
do
clear

echo -e " \t *******************************************************************"
echo -e " \t ******************** TEST-MENU ********************************"
echo -e  "\t *******************************************************************"
echo -e  "\n"
echo -e "\t\t 1)Show Date/Time"
echo -e "\t\t 2)File-Search"
echo -e "\t\t e)End \n"

echo -e "\t\t Select your choice:\c" ;  read answer
echo -e  "\t*******************************************************************"


case $answer in
1)date +'%y%m%d %H:%M:%S' ;;
2)echo -e "Please give your dir:\c" ; read directory
        if [ "$directory"  = "" ]    then
        $directory = "[/test/sample/]" fi

echo -e "Enter your file [$directory]:\c" ; read search
        find "$directory" -name "*$search*" -type f -print|xargs ls -l ;;

e) exit ;;

esac
echo -e "Enter return to continue \c"
read answer

done
```

Comment: If you don't insist on that exact display of the menu, look into the `select` command. It already provides a way of displaying a menu of choices, selecting an item, and acting on that selection.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of issues:

- Variable assignment

  $directory = "[/test/sample/]" fi

You don't use $ when you are assigning the value, so you should use like

directory="[/test/sample/]" fi

- your default directory

  $directory = "[/test/sample/]" fi

Why would you need square bracket? are you doing ls [/test/sample]? Just remove it.

- your if

  if [ "$directory"  = "" ]

  if user just press enter then it's not going to work so you should do it like:

  if [ "X$directory"  = "X" ]
- you could combine ls and find like:

  find "$directory" -name "*$search*" -type f -exec ls -l {} \;

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example with some formatting edits and comments added.  You need some testing for null on the search filename though, as if it does not exist it shows the files in the current dir:

```
#!/bin/bash
trap '' 2

# Set up the default value. If you ever want to change it, just do it here.
# -r means make it read-only so this makes it a CONSTANT.
declare -r DEFAULT=1

while true
  do
  clear

  echo -e " \t *******************************************************************"
  echo -e " \t ************************ TEST-MENU ********************************"
  echo -e  "\t *******************************************************************"
  echo -e  "\n"
  echo -e "\t\t 1)Show Date/Time"
  echo -e "\t\t 2)File-Search"
  echo -e "\t\t e)End \n"

  # Typically in a prompt like this
  #  when there is a value in square brackets that means if you just
  #  press enter you will get that value as the default.
  echo -e "\t\t Select your choice [$DEFAULT]: \c" ;  read answer
  echo -e  "\t*******************************************************************"

  # If nothing was selected, use the default.
  # -z tests for null.
  if [[ -z "$answer" ]]
    then answer=$DEFAULT
  fi

  case $answer in
    1) date +'%y%m%d %H:%M:%S'
       ;;
    2) echo -e "Please give your dir: \c"
       read directory
       if [[ -z "$directory" ]] # Test for null
         then directory="/test/sample/"
       fi

       echo -e "Enter your file [$directory]: \c"
       read search
       find "$directory" -name "*$search*" -type f -print|xargs ls -l
       ;;
    e) exit
       ;;

    # Always expect the unexpected!  The * is the default for a case
    #  statement when no match is found.
    *) echo -e "[$answer] is an invalid selection"
       ;;
  esac

  echo -e "Enter return to continue \c"
  read answer
done
```